# Usage of Bluetooth Major Class of Device code "Uncategorized"

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to understand the usage of the Bluetooth Major Device Class code "Uncategorized". The Bluetooth SIG "Assigned Numbers" document appears to indicate this class should be used on a temporary basis only:

*A device that does not have a Major Class Code assigned can use the ”Uncategorized: device code not specified” code until classified.*

(from section 2.8.2 "Major Device Class")

The statement is of a general nature and not binding i.e. it does not give a limit on how long the class should be used for, or under what circumstances.

Is there any further information on the usage of this "Uncategorized" class? I could not locate any in Bluetooth SIG documentation or elsewhere.